having a main function in a library crate
I have created a project with lib.rs to implement some functionality that I want to be then used in other projects.
src/lib.rs

Is is possible to also have a main function in some source file in same project which I can execute independently of library code just to test my rust understandings?
I have no plan to retain it though, and would remove it once my library is ready.
